# Why is $(3, 1+\sqrt{-26})^3=( 1+\sqrt{-26})$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-26}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ideals

$a = 3, b = 1+\sqrt{-26}$ then $(a,b)^3=(a^3,b^3,a^2b,ab^2)$

each generator except $a^3$ has a $b$ factor and $\bar b b=27$, so $"\subseteq"$. Now the question is how to obtain $b$ using these generators. Is there a general formula, which states in which case this is possible or even is  there an algorithm. I made it very complicated I think;

$a^3 = 27,\quad$
$b^3 = -77+23\sqrt{-26},\quad$
$a^2b = 9+9\sqrt{-26},\quad$
$ab^2 = -75+6\sqrt{-26}$

$3*a^3+ab^2=81+(-75+6\sqrt{-26})=6+6\sqrt{-26}$

$a^2b-ans = 3+3\sqrt{-26}$

are these correct so far ?

Comment: Here it suffices to check $\,a\,$ is coprime to $\rm\color{#0af}{trace}$ of $\,b,\,$ indeed $(3,\color{#0af}2)=1,\,$ see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True by below, $ $ since here: $\,a\!=\!3,\,b+\bar b=\color{#0af}2\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{(a,b,\bar b)} = (3,b,\bar b,\color{#0af}2)=1$.

**Lemma**  $\, $ If $\  a^3 = b\bar b\ $ then $\ (a,b)^3 = (b)\iff  \color{#0a0}{(a,b,\bar b)}=1$

**Proof** $\ \ (a,b)^3\! = (b)((\bar b)\!+\!(a,b)^2) = (b)\!\iff\!$  $(\bar b)\!+\!(a,b)^2\! = 1\!\!\!\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm EL}\!\!}\iff\!$
$\color{#0a0}{(\bar b)\!+\!(a,b)}=1$

Comment: We used $\color{#c00}{\rm EL}$ = Euclid's Lemma: $I\!+\!J=1 \,\Rightarrow\, I\!+\!JJ = I\!+\!IJ\!+\!JJ = I\!+\!(I\!+\!J)J = I\!+\!J = 1\ \ $

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4606057/242) for a generalization of the Lemma from principal to any ideals.

Answer (score 2):

I think $b^3$ should be $-77 - 23\sqrt{-26}$ which makes $-(2a^3 + b^3) = 23(1+\sqrt{-26})$ and you have already found $6(1+\sqrt{-26})$ in the ideal. Together they will give you $1+\sqrt{-26}$.
I have not come across any general method for these.

Comment: Or $3a^3+\sqrt{-26}a=4b$. As $a^2b=9b$ is in there, the same conclusion follows. Many ways to do this, and yours works. There is a simple algorithmic way of finding generators for this ideal *as a free abelian group* using Smith normal form type of algorithms. Don't know whether that helps? It should simplify things at the very least.

Comment: I thought there should be algorithms, probably similar to algorithms for solving linear equations.

Answer (score 2):

To be explicit, you could use linear algebra:

$$\begin{align}
a^3&=27&&\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}27\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
b^3&=-77-23\sqrt{-26}&&\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}-77\\-23\end{bmatrix}\\
a^2b&=9+9\sqrt{-26}&&\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}9\\9\end{bmatrix}\\
ab^2&=-75+6\sqrt{-26}&&\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}-75\\6\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}$$

It would suffice to have an integer solution to the equation $$wa^3+xb^3+ya^2b+zab^2=b$$ The corresponding augmented matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
27&-77&9&-75&1\\
0&-23&9&6&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This reduces to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
23&0&-18&-81&-2\\
0&23&-9&-6&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$

You need choices for $y$ and $z$ such that $18y+81z-2$ and $9y+6z-1$ are each divisible by $23$. In other words, you want to solve
$$\begin{bmatrix}
18&81\\
9&6
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

modulo $23$. So we can again use linear algebra (with some division mod $23$) to find

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
18&81\\
9&6
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

We can just go with $y=2$ and $z=1$. This gives $(w,x,y,z)=(5,1,2,1)$. So it seems that
$$5a^3+b^3+2a^2b+ab^2=b$$

Comment: This is good. But numbers like $\sqrt{-26}a$ et cetera are also in the ideal (may or may not be needed to get the desired outcome).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, and maybe it's too subtle but I meant to acknowledge that with the "It would suffice..." line.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Anyway, with this kind of coordinates you always get a basis for the ideal as a free abelian group. And that generalizes to other number fields (once you have identified an integral basis).