# The ideal $I=(3,1+\sqrt{-23})\subseteq \mathcal O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Intro:

$K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-23})$ be a number field with obvious minimum polynomial.

$\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers which is determined as $$\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}\right]$$
since $-23\equiv 1 \mod 4$

I want to determine if $I,I^2,I^3$ are principal or not.

I was able to calculate norm of $I$ as: $N(I)=3$.

Then using basic ideas I can show that $I$ is not principal.

$N(I^2)=9=\left(x+y/2\right)^2+\frac{23}4y^2=3^2$

Only solution is $x=\pm 3,y=0$

Why we can't say that $I^2$ is generated by the ideal $(3)$?

I want to show $I^3$ is principal ideal.

Norm is multiplicative so $N(I^3)=27$

So $N(I^3)=27=\left(x+y/2\right)^2+\frac{23}4y^2=3^3$

Has following integer solutions $(x,y)=(-3,2),(-1,2),(1,2),(3,-2)$

And I am stuct to find which one is appropriate candidate, which kind of theorem says/guarantees that?

Comment: Have you tried computing $I^2$? What are its generators?

Comment: yes but it seems messy $(9,3+3\sqrt{-23},-22+2\sqrt{-23})$

Comment: Though it’s obvious from context, you never actually defined the background ring, and $I$ is only defined in the title (it is better to put all relevant details in the question as well)

Comment: It may be messy (to calculate $I^2$ and $I^3$), but it's the way to go. Any ring with $9$ and $-22+2\sqrt{-23}$ also has $5+2\sqrt{-23}$. Try doing calculations like that to get down from three generators to two.

Comment: A possibly flashier example of the technique in KCd's answer is shown in [this older variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84131/11619).

Comment: I simplified my answer - making it an easy two line proof of everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$w\!=\!\sqrt{-23},\ I\! =\! \overbrace{(3,w\!-\!2)}^{\textstyle (3,w\!+\!1)}$ $\Rightarrow \color{darkorange}{3^3}\!\in I^3$ $\Rightarrow\overbrace{\color{c00}{(\color{#c00}{w\!-\!2})(\color{#0a0}{w\!+\!2})}\in I^3}^{\textstyle w^2\!-\!4 = \color{darkorange}{-3^3\ \ \ [*]}},\:$ $\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}{w\!+\!2},I^3)\!=\!1}^{{\textstyle  (w\!+\!2,I)\!=\!1}}$ $\overbrace{\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{w\!-\!2\in I^3}}^{\color{#0af}{\rm EL=}\text{Euclid's Lemma}\!\!}$ using [EL](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242). $ $ [Hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533044/242)  $\,I^3=((3,w\!-\!2)^3,\color{#c00}{w\!-\!2})^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!\! = (3^3,w\!-\!2) \overset{\color{darkorange}{[*]}}= (w\!-\!2)\,$ [so $I^2$ is not principal, else $I^3 = I I^2\Rightarrow I^{\phantom{|^{|}}}\!\!\!$ principal]. $\ \small\bf QED$

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem, it is not necessary to compute powers of $I$ explicitly in terms of generators from knowing generators of $I$. Instead we can focus on the norm of powers of $I$ and reason indirectly by factoring ideals into prime ideals.

The ideal $I$ has prime norm $3$, so it is a prime ideal. (The converse is false: prime ideals need not have prime norm.) So $I^2$ has norm $9$ and $I^3$ has norm $27$.

Are there principal ideals with norm $3$?  Let $\alpha = (1 + \sqrt{-23})/2$. For integers $m$ and $n$,
$$
 {\rm N}(m + n\alpha) = {\rm N}\left(m + n\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}\right) = \frac{(2m+n)^2 + 23n^2}{4}, 
$$
so if ${\rm N}(m+n\alpha) = 3$ then $(2m+n)^2 + 23n^2 = 12$.
The left side is a sum of nonnegative terms, so the only choice is $n = 0$. Then $(2m)^2 = 12$, which has no integral solution.

Now we turn to $I^2$. It has norm $9$. Can $I^2$ be principal?
If $(m + n\alpha)$ has norm $9$ for some integers $m$ and $n$, then
$$
9 = {\rm N}(m + n\alpha) = \frac{(2m+n)^2 + 23n^2}{4}, 
$$
so $(2m+n)^2 + 23n^2 = 36$.  This implies $|n| \leq 1$. If $n = \pm 1$ then $(2m+n)^2 = 36 - 23 = 13$, which is impossible.  Thus $n = 0$, so $(2m)^2 = 36$, which tells us $m = \pm 3$. Thus $(m+n\alpha) = (\pm 3) = (3)$.

Can $I^2 = (3)$? No, because we can determine the prime ideal factorization of $(3)$ from the factorization mod $3$ of the minimal polynomial $T^2 - T + 6$ for $\alpha$: $T^2 - T + 6 \equiv T(T-1) \bmod 3$, which is a product of distinct monic irreducibles, so $(3) = \mathfrak p\mathfrak q$ where $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$ are distinct prime ideals.  So $(3)$ is not the square of the prime ideal $I$ (unique factorization!) and either $\mathfrak p$ or $\mathfrak q$ is $I$.

Now we turn to $I^3$. It has norm $27$.  If a principal ideal $(m+n\alpha)$ has norm $27$ then
$$
27 = {\rm N}(m + n\alpha) = \frac{(2m+n)^2 + 23n^2}{4},
$$
so $(2m+n)^2 + 23n^2 = 108$. That implies $|n| \leq 2$, and trying each option gives us the solutions
$$
(m,n) = (1,2), (-3, 2), (3,-2), (-1,-2), 
$$
so $(m+n\alpha)$ is $(1+2\alpha) = (2+\sqrt{-23})$ or it is $(3-2\alpha) = (2-\sqrt{-23})$.  We have shown the only principal ideals in $\mathcal O_K$ with norm $27$ are $(2\pm \sqrt{-23})$. Thus we want to factor these into prime ideals to see if either of them is $I^3$.

Since the ideals $(2+ \sqrt{-23})$ and $(2-\sqrt{-23})$ have norm $27$, their only prime ideal factors in $\mathcal O_K$ are prime ideal factors of $3$ (see my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604503/how-to-determine-the-ideal-in-a-ring-of-integers-of-a-number-field-corresponds-t)).  We noted above that $(3) = \mathfrak p\mathfrak q$ for distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$ (where $I$ is one of them). So the only possible ideals in $\mathcal O_K$ with norm $27$ are
$$
\mathfrak p^3, \ \ \mathfrak p^2\mathfrak q, \ \ 
\mathfrak p\mathfrak q^2, \ \ \mathfrak q^3.
$$

The ideal $(2+\sqrt{-23})$ is not divisible by *both* $\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak q$, since if it were then it would be divisible by their product $(3)$, and if $(3) \mid (2+\sqrt{-23})$ as principal ideals then $3 \mid (2+\sqrt{-23})$ as elements,  but $2+\sqrt{-23}$ is not $3(a + b(1+\sqrt{-23})/2)$ for integers $a$ and $b$.  Therefore the only possible
prime ideal factorization of $(2+\sqrt{-23})$ is $\mathfrak p^3$ or $\mathfrak q^3$.  The exact same reasoning shows $(2-\sqrt{-23})$ is $\mathfrak p^3$ or $\mathfrak q^3$.  And since the ideals $(2+\sqrt{-23})$ and $(2-\sqrt{-23})$ are different (they're principal ideals whose generators don't have a ratio that's a unit in $\mathcal O_K$, or in fact even lies in $\mathcal O_K$), their prime ideal factorizations are different. Thus if we let $\mathfrak p$ be the prime ideal such that $(2+\sqrt{-23}) = \mathfrak p^3$, then $(2-\sqrt{-23}) = \mathfrak q^3$.

Since $I$ is $\mathfrak p$ or $\mathfrak q$, we get $I^3 = (2+\sqrt{-23})$ or $I^3 = (2-\sqrt{-23})$.  Which one is it?

Recall that $I = (3,1+\sqrt{-23})$, so easily
$$
2-\sqrt{-23} = 3 - (1+\sqrt{-23}) \in I.
$$
Thus $(2-\sqrt{-23}) \subset I$, so $I \mid (2-\sqrt{-23})$. Therefore $(2-\sqrt{-23}) = I^3$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very famous question. Repeated many times. Every time I see it, I think that I don't know the solution! I am an amateur number theorist. This is neither a complete nor systematic solution. If you see mistakes please comment. I wonder if there is a systematic solution for such questions.

Let $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}$ then, $x^2=x-6$.
Let $I=(3,1+\sqrt{-23})$. Then,
$$I=(3,2x)=(3,-2x+3x)=(3,x).$$
The norm of $I$ is $N(I)=|\Bbb{Z}[x]/I|=|\Bbb{Z}_3|=3$.

For any number $a+bx\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, $N(a+bx)=a^2+ab+6b^2$. If $I=(\alpha)$ were principal then $N(I)=N(\alpha)=3.$ But this is impossible as the possible norms are:
$$0,1,6,8,9,12,16,18,23,24,25,26,...$$
So $I$ is not principal as OP told. Next,
$$I^2=(9,3x,x^2)=(9,3x,x+3)=(9,x+3).$$
Then, $N(I^2)=9.$ Norm of ideal trick doesn't work. Suppose $I^2=(\alpha)$ is principal. Then $(a+bx)\alpha=9$ and $(c+dx)\alpha=x+3$ for some integers $a,b,c,d.$ Hence, $(a^2+ab+6b^2)N(\alpha)=81$ and $(c^2+cd+6d^2)=18.$ From these equations, it is easy to deduce that $N(\alpha)=1.$ So, without loss of generality $\alpha=1$. But then, for some integers $a,b,c,d$, $(a+bx)9+(c+dx)(x+3)=1$ which gives
$9a+3c-6d=1$ which is impossible. So, $I^2$ is not principle. Next,
$$I^3=I.I^2=(27,3x+9,9x,x^2+3x)=(27,3x+9,4x-6)=(27,3x+9,x+12)=(27,x+12)=(2x-3).$$
For the last equality, we observe that
$$(-2x-1)(2x-3)=27,$$
$$(-x)(2x-3)=x+12,$$
$$2(x+12)-27=2x-3.$$
So $I^3$ is principal with norm $N(I^3)=N(2x-3)=27$.

Comment: You omitted perhaps the most important step - how you discovered  (and proved) that $2x-3$ generates $I^3 =( 27,x+12)$. Since that is the primary goal one shouldn't just pull it out of a hat like magic.

Comment: Your edit *verifies* the equality but still doesn't say how you  discovered the generator. Note also that $I\cdot I^2 = I^3$ is principal, so $ I^2$ is principal $\!\iff\! I$ is principal, so it suffices to show $I$ is nonprincipal.

Comment: @BillDubuque I took the derivative of $x^2-3x$. Kidding. What?! Trial and error. I don't know how I found.

Comment: How did you find the generator by "trial and error"? Since this is the key step in showing $I^3$ principal you should explain how you did it.

Comment: I knew that it was principal ideal. Its norm is $27$. So, I checked the numbers whose norm is $27$. But, I think you expect deeper explanations than that.  I don't know.

Comment: If you mean that you tested all elements of norm $27$ to see if they lie in the ideal and generate it then you should say that *in the answer*. Lacking that the generator is pulled out of a hat like magic - but magic is not math!

Comment: There were not so many choices. But, again, I don't know these bounds well.

Comment: I posted an answer showing a quick simple way to compute the generator without pulling anything out of a hat.

Comment: I didn't think modular in my solution. But I agree it helps to see things better.

Comment: It's more ideal arithmetic than modular. I simplified my answer to highlight that.

Answer (score 2):

$I^3=(b)\,$ by below: put $\,a\!=\!3,\, b= 2\!-\!\sqrt{-23},\,$ so $ \,b\!+\!\bar b=\color{#0af}4\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{(a,b,\bar b)} = (3,b,\bar b,\color{#0af}4)=(1)$.

[Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490860/242)  $\, $ If $\ \color{#c00}{(a^3) = (b\bar b)}\ $ then $\ (a,b)^3 = (b)\!\iff\!  \color{#0a0}{(a,b,\bar b)}=(1),\,$ by $\rm\color{#c00}{EL}$ = [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242).

**Proof** $\ \ (\color{#c00}a,b)^{\color{#c00}3}\! = \color{#c00}{(b)}(\color{#c00}{(\bar b)}\!+\!(a,b)^2) = (b)\!\iff\!$  $(\bar b)\!+\!(a,b)^2\! = (1)\!\!\!\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm EL}\!\!}\iff\!$
$\color{#0a0}{(\bar b)\!+\!(a,b)}=(1)$

Comment: **Lemma**  $\, $ Let $J,K,\bar K$ be ideals in a commutative ring, with $K$  cancellable (e.g. principal).
$\tag*{}$
If we have $\ \color{#c00}{J^3 = K\bar K}\ $ then $\ (J\!+\!K)^3 = K\!\iff\!  \color{#0a0}{J\!+\!K\!+\!\bar K}=(1),\,$ by $\rm\color{#c00}{EL}$ = [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242).  
$\tag*{}$
**Proof** $\ \ (\color{#c00}J\!+\!K)^{\color{#c00}3}\! = \color{#c00}{K}(\color{#c00}{\bar K}\!+\!(J\!+\!K)^2) = K\!\iff\!$  $\bar K\!+\!(J+K)^2\! =\! (1)\!\smash[t]{\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm EL}\!\!}\iff\!}$
$\color{#0a0}{\bar K\!+\!(J\!+\!K)}\!=\!(1)\ \ $

Comment: $(A,a)=1\iff (A,a^2)=1$... Is this the point?